# How to de-unzip, de-tar -xvf -- de-unarchive in a messy folder?

Tags: archive, tar, zip, file-management

Usually, I unarchive things by `$ mkdir newFolder; $ mv *.zip newFolder; $ cd newFolder; $unzip *.zip` but sometimes I get lazy and just do in an arbitrary folder `$ unzip *.zip` so time-to-time messing up with other content.  I will list here some methods -- some archive version surely have crappy-flags while others more spartan, I am more interested about the latter.

**Some ways to de-unarchive, are there others?**

1. `$ find . -anewer fileThatExistedBeforeUnarchieving -ok rm '{}' \;` Weaknesses are that it lists the `*.zip` dirs, so you need to use slow `-ok`, slow with many `*.zip` matches and, for some reason, it does not seem to match everything extracted.
2. If small amount of extracted files, one-by-one, slow, cumbersome and error-prone.
3. When I want to make sure whether the content of the archieve is actually a folder, I sometimes check it with `$ unzip -l *.bsd`, works at least in obsd`s unzip-version.

If you are referring to certain archiving tools, please, state them when appropriate. Keep it simple though  -- I am more interested about the WAYS how you do it, rather than a single tool.

Comment: See also [Accidental Extract Location - How to Clean Up?](http://superuser.com/questions/198769/accidental-extract-location-how-to-clean-up)

Comment: Here's a script I use to automate the `mkdir; unzip` stuff so I'm never too lazy to do it!  http://svn.mikelward.com/svn/scripts/untar

Comment: See this related question and answers: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5123/how-to-de-unzip-de-tar-xvf-de-unarchive-in-a-messy-folder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### By name

You can generate the list of files in the archive and delete them, though this is annoyingly fiddly with archivers such as unzip or 7z that don't have an option to generate a plain list of file names. Even with tar, this assumes there are no newlines in file names.

```
tar tf foo.tar | while read -r file; do rm -- "$file" done
unzip -l foo.zip | awk '
    p && /^ --/ {p=2}
    p==1 {print substr($0, 29)}
    /^ --/ {++p}
' | while …
unzip -l foo.zip | tail -n +4 | head -n -2 | while …  # GNU coreutils only
7z l -slt foo.zip | sed -n 's/^Path = //p' | while …  # works on tar.*, zip, 7z and more
```

Instead of removing the files, you could move them to their intended destination.

```
tar tf foo.tar | while read -r file; do
  if [ -d "$file" ]; then continue; fi
  mkdir -p "/intended/destination/${file%/*}"
  mv -- "$file" "/intended/destination/$file"
done
```

#### Using FUSE

Instead of depending on external tools, you can (on most unices) use [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) to manipulate archives using ordinary filesystem commands.

You can use [Fuse-zip](http://code.google.com/p/fuse-zip/) to peek into a zip, extract it with `cp`, list its contents with `find`, etc.

```
mkdir /tmp/foo.d
fuse-zip foo.zip /tmp/foo.d
## Remove the files that were extracted mistakenly (GNU/BSD find)
(cd /tmp/foo.d && find . \! -type d -print0) | xargs -0 rm
## Remove the files that were extracted mistakenly (zsh)
rm /tmp/foo.d/**(:"s~/tmp/foo.d/~~"^/)
## Extract the contents where you really want them
cp -Rp /tmp/foo.d /intended/destination
fusermount -u foo.d
rmdir foo.d
```

[AVFS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/avf/) creates a view of your entire directory hierarchy where all archives have an associated directory (same name with # tacked on at the end) that appears to hold the archive content.

```
mountavfs
## Remove the files that were extracted mistakenly (GNU/BSD find)
(cd ~/.avfs/"$PWD/foo.zip#" && find . \! -type d -print0) | xargs -0 rm
## Remove the files that were extracted mistakenly (zsh)
rm ~/.avfs/$PWD/foo.zip\#/**/*(:"s~$HOME/.avfs/$PWD/foo.zip#~~"^/)
## Extract the contents where you really want them
cp -Rp ~/.avfs/"$PWD/foo.zip#" /intended/destination
umountavfs
```

#### By date

Assuming there hasn't been other any activity in the same hierarchy than your extraction, you can tell the extracted files by their recent [**ctime**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28Unix%29). If you just created or moved the zip file, you can use it as a cutoff; otherwise use `ls -lctr` to determine a suitable cutoff time. If you want to make sure not to remove the zips, there's no reason to do any manual approval: `find` is perfectly capable of excluding them. Here are example commands using zsh or `find`; note that the `-cmin` and `-cnewer` primaries are not in POSIX but exist on Linux (and other systems with GNU find), *BSD and OSX.

```
find . \! -name '*.zip' -type f -cmin -5 -exec rm {} +  # extracted <5 min ago
rm **/*~*.zip(.cm-6)  # zsh, extracted ≤5 min ago
find . -type f -cnewer foo.zip -exec rm {} +  # created or moved after foo.zip
```

With GNU find, FreeBSD and OSX, another way to specify the cutoff time is to create a file and use `touch` to set its mtime to the cutoff time.

```
touch -d … cutoff
find . -type f -newercm cutoff -delete
```

Instead of removing the files, you could move them to their intended destination. Here's a way with GNU/*BSD/OSX find, creating directories in the destination as needed.

```
find . \! -name . -cmin -5 -type f -exec sh -c '
    for x; do
      mkdir -p "$0/${x%/*}"
      mv "$x" "$0/$x"
    done
  ' /intended/destination {} +
```

Zsh equivalent (almost: this one reproduces the entire directory hierarchy, not just the directories that will contain files):

```
autoload zmv
mkdir -p ./**/*(/cm-3:s"|.|/intended/destination|")
zmv -Q '(**/)(*)(.cm-3)' /intended/destination/'$1$2'
```

---

Warning, I haven't tested most of the commands in this answer. Always review the list of files before removing (run `echo` first, then `rm` if it's ok).

Comment: I finally run into this problem today. As root! In the end I used a combination of "By name" and "By date"

Answer (score 1):

I'm feeling stupid, anyway I scratched my head to write up this script when I had a similar problem. I used `cpio` with the `-it` flag to get a list of files; you can use equivalent commands for other archivers. The tricky part is, the cpio archive is from an initrd and I extracted into `/`, so many folders and files have the same name as in a working system. Luckily cpio didn't overwrite any of my existing files. I use a time check to ensure not to delete anything that existed before the wrong command.

```
#! /bin/sh

files=$(cpio -it < /mnt/temp/lglive.cpio)

for i in ${files}
do
    name=$(stat -c "%n" ${i})
    time=$(stat -c "%Y" ${i})
    # Time of the creation of the mess: 1296457595
    if [[ ${time} -gt 1296457590 && ${time} -lt 1296457600 ]]
    then
        if [[ -f ${name} ]]
        # If it is a file, it must have been created as part of the mess.
        then
            echo "rm ${name}"
        elif [[ -d ${name} ]]
        # If it is a directory, it may have been part of the mess
        # or maybe some files underneath it is created as part of the mess.
        then
            if [[ $(ls -A ${name}) ]]
            # If the directory contains something then don't delete it.
            then
                echo "${name} is not empty"
            # If the directory is empty then assume it is rubbish.
            else
                echo "rmdir ${name}"
            fi
        fi
    fi
done

echo "Files and directories still exist after the removal:"
for i in ${files}
do
    if [[ -e ${i} ]]
    then
        echo ${i}
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

How about feeding the list of files in archive to `xargs rm`?

That would be `tar -tf tarbomb.tar | xargs rm` or `unzip --list zipbomb.zip | xargs rm`.

Comment: The commands as given won't work in the general case, and this is **dangerous** since you're removing files. `xargs` expects its input quoted in a peculiar way that `find` does not produce. Use `xargs -I rm {}` so that xargs processes one item per line instead. For the unzip command, what implementation do you have? Mine (Debian/Ubuntu) doesn't have `--list`, only `-l`, and it doesn't just print file names, so that extra processing is needed.

Comment: @Gilles: 1) yes, it's dangerous, but since we've presumably overwritten the original files -- they're already gone. 2) I wasn't talking about `find`. 3) you are correct about `unzip`, I didn't test and there seem to be no option for undecorated listing.  No `--list` on my Ubuntu as well -- I just didn't test.

Comment: Sorry about the canned response, substitute `tar -t` for `find`. But my other points stand. There is a real risk that your command as given would delete an unrelated file.

Comment: `tar -tf tarbomb.tar` will print file names one per line, so you could do `tar -tf tarbomb.tar | while IFS=$'\n' read -r filename; do rm "$filename"; done` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Not really what you asked for but how about to use a "unzip all" script instead of.

```
unzip *.zip
```

That way the output from each file goes into it's own directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.zip ; do unzip -n "$f" -d "${f/%zip/out}"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function in zsh:


`ununzip () {
    rm -r $(unzip -l $1 | grep -v 'Archive:' | \
    grep '[/.]' | sed 's![^a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z./])!\1!')
}`

I.e. command substitution to remove all files in the cleaned up output of `unzip -l`.

`tar tvf` could be used in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

A had an issue with unzip recently, the `--list` command did nothing on Ubuntu/Kali (Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008), by Info-ZIP) while the `-l` exports in useless human readable format. So I've happily ended up with tar-xargs-based example:

`zipinfo -1 ./archive.zip | xargs rm -rf`