# Clean up / after accidentally extracting archive into it?

Tags: root, archive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to de-unzip, de-tar -xvf — de-unarchive in a messy folder?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5123/how-to-de-unzip-de-tar-xvf-de-unarchive-in-a-messy-folder)

I have just accidentally extracted a cpio archive as root into `/`. Now my `/` is littered with junks. What is a proper way to clean up those files?