# Delete files in a directory which are also in another directory

Tags: shell-script, files, directory, cp

I copied a directory using this:

```
cp -r dir/ ../../
```

without thinking and realized that it copied the contents of `dir` instead of actually `dir` to the above directory. Now I have a mess of files I need to delete so I can redo the `cp` correctly. How can I delete all the files that I mistakenly copied over if they don't match anything in particular?

Comment: Related: [How to de-unzip, de-tar -xvf -- de-unarchive in a messy folder?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5123)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, this is basically the same as [klapaucius' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19835/delete-files-in-a-directory-which-are-also-in-another-directory/19836#19836).
(And it won't repair any damage done if `cp` has overwritten some existing files.)

Assuming you are in the source directory (in `dir`). This command:

```
find . -type f -exec echo '{}' ';'
```

will list all the files (recursively) present in your `dir` directory (quite like `-print`). The `-type f` option is there to prevent the listing of sub-directories.

So, if you use:

```
find dir -type f -exec echo '../../../{}' ';'
```

This should list corresponding files (copies) in the target directory.

Now if the list is correct, you will be able to remove the copies using:

```
find dir -type f -exec rm -- '../../../{}' ';'
```

As for pruning remaining empty directories that come from the `cp`… hum…

Comment: I'm using the `echo` method to double check the file names first. However, I need to change `dir` to `.` or else it doesn't seem to work. Also, it only lists the files in `dir`, not the ones also in `../..`

Comment: Ah yes, I got confused by your description. Why did `cp` copy the content and not the directory in this case?

Comment: No clue, I ran `cp -r ./dir/ ../../`

Comment: Ah! that's cause of the final `/`!

Comment: The one in `./dir/`? Should it have been `./dir` instead?

Comment: Yes, but this happens only with some `cp` versions it seems… Mine (coreutils 8.12) has not this behavior anymore. (It was useful sometimes.)

Comment: In such cases what I do is to send the filelist to some temporary file, say `/tmp/lst`, which I can check carefully (or even edit), and when I'm OK, I go `rm -f $(< /tmp/lst)` (the `$(<`is a bash(1)ism, in standard sh(1) it would be the cumbersome `rm -f \`cat /tmp/lst\`

Comment: @stéphane Assuming existing directories `a` and `b`:  

Saying `cp -r a b` means "copy the directory named `a` into directory `b` using the same name `a` under `b`", so you create `b/a` and put all the files under it.  

Saying `cp -r a/ b` is the same as `cp -r a/. b` which also means "copy the directory named `a/.` into directory `b` using the same name `.` under `b`".  Of course you don't create `b/.` because it's already there, and so all the files go under `b/.` not under `b/a`.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Yes, I see now that some versions of `cp` take `a/` to mean `a/.` and some don't.  Ubuntu 12.04 does; CentOS 6.5 doesn't.  Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` in combination with `-exec`. Better test with `ls` before like this:

```
find . -name "*" -exec ls ../../{} \;
```

Comment: What exactly is this doing? For every file in `.` (the copied dir), it sees if it is also two directories up? To remove them I use `rm` instead of `ls`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry, forgot to explain it

Comment: Dont worry about it, I'll test this first before trying it on my server :)

Comment: I get `find: missing argument to '-exec'`

Comment: Do you have a blank between {} and \; ?

Answer (score 1):

The following code handles file names which contain embedded newlines
I've put a full version script on [paste.ubuntu](http://paste.ubuntu.com/679096/). It checks for existance and matching sizes... The code to generate the test data is also included there.

```
# This lists the original fully-qualified filename, 
# and its would-be counterpart (assuming it exists) 
unset a i
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' relf; do
    printf "%s\n$s" "$PWD${relf:1}" "$(dirname "$(dirname "$PWD")")${relf:1}"
done < <(find  . -type f  \! -name '.' -name '*' -print0)
```

---

Here is a sample output of the full version (mentioned above), where one file is missing, and another has a different file size to the original

```
WARNING -----
NOT in target   ./file1
ok --------
sizes match     ./c/file4-in-subdir
WARNING ------
size mis-match  ./file3   is   triple-spaced
ok --------
sizes match     ./file2
has newline!
```

Answer (score -2):

You want to remove into PATH_DIR1 existing files in PATH_DIR2 :

```
find PATH_DIR1 -type f  -exec basename '{}' ';' | xargs printf -- 'PATH_DIR2/%s\n' | xargs rm
```

Explanations :

1. List all filenames in PATH_DIR1

> find PATH_DIR1 -type f  -exec basename '{}' ';'

2. Filter the previous listing with the existing files in PATH_DIR2 (find the intersect data)

> xargs printf -- 'PATH_DIR2/%s\n'

3. Execute the remove action to the filtered result

> xargs rm

Comment: Would you mind describing the various steps of your pipeline while also mentioning any restrictions or pitfalls (filenames containing spaces may be an issue, for example)?  Are you deliberately skipping over directories?