# How to undo an unrar?

Tags: archive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to de-unzip, de-tar -xvf — de-unarchive in a messy folder?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5123/how-to-de-unzip-de-tar-xvf-de-unarchive-in-a-messy-folder)

I just extracted a RAR archive that contained a lot of files in the base directory. Assuming that there were no filename collisions, what's the easiest way to remove the files just created? Parsing `unrar -l` seems troublesome due to filename variety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unrar lb archive.rar` to get a list of bare filenames, one per line.  As long as none of the filenames contained newlines, this should be trivial to parse:

```
unrar lb archive.rar | perl -ne 'chomp; -d ? rmdir : unlink'
```