# Remove accidentally extracted files

Tags: rm, archive, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to de-unzip, de-tar -xvf — de-unarchive in a messy folder?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5123/how-to-de-unzip-de-tar-xvf-de-unarchive-in-a-messy-folder)

This is a pretty annoying occurrence. Sometimes, I download an archive (`tar.gz, tar.bz2, zip, rar, etc`) and run `tar xf [file]` (or similar) in the file's directory. In rare occasions, all the files extract in the current working directory instead of a sub-directory. This can lead to hundreds of files and hundreds of patterns that can't simply be removed using a pattern matching solution.

Is there a way to get the file contents of an archive and then delete all files on that list in the current working directory?

Comment: I hate tar-bombs, so I always create a subdirectory, put the archive there and uncompress it. Just in case. An efective way is also to always redirect the verbose list of extracted files to a file, so you have a list of what to remove if this happens.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can list the content of the archive and then pass the list to rm using xargs

Example for a tarball (test it without the `rm` first):

```
tar tfz archive.tar.gz | xargs rm -rf
```

For *.zip* files, replace `tar tfz archive.tar.gz` with `unzip -Z1 file.zip` (or equivalently `zipinfo -1 file.zip`) (ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128304/368910)

Comment: It's definitely the smartest way to do it.

Comment: How could it be for a zip file?

Comment: first output line is `.`, omit with `| sed '1d' | xargs rm -rf`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming all the files were extracted on the same date/time, you could write a one-liner and pass the regex to `rm`.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit, in particular to distinguish your response from the already accepted one? Would the one-liner use `find` based on the mtime? And where do regexes come into this at all?