# How to undo and revert an accidental `7z e`

Tags: files, 7z

I accidentally typed

```
7z e archive.7z
```

and all the files ended up in my home directory when I wanted to extract them in a subfolder. How can I clean the mess and remove all those files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25006/48590) and [that one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134219/48590) in particular, I ended up running this command which removed all the unwanted files:

```
7z l archive.zip | awk ' {print $6} ' | awk '
  function basename(file) {
    sub(".*/", "", file)
    return file
  }
  {print basename($1)} ' | xargs rm -rf
```